# No Ubuntu Desktop/desktop icons on ubuntu unity

Tags: 20.04, unity

I installed `ubuntu-unity-desktop` on my system to replace GNOME but after installation there were no desktop icons or the Ubuntu desktop itself. I also cannot add icons from the Unity Tweak Tool. I also tried creating a folder in the desktop directory but as expected, nothing happened.
Is there any fix to this issue? maybe it did not install correctly? (i tried reinstalling it though)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Show Desktop]

Show Desktop Icon on the Unity Dash can be added by:

[image: Unity_Tweak]